# IBM watson Speech to text integration

Tags: java, android, ibm-watson

Hi I want to transcript running video using speech to text of IBM Watson library. My code is:

```
new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                    .audio(audio)
                    .contentType("audio/mp3")
                    .model("en-US_BroadbandModel")
                    .interimResults(true)
                    .inactivityTimeout(2000)
                    //TODO: Uncomment this to enable Speaker Diarization
                    .speakerLabels(true)
                    .build();
```

I am getting following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to transcode data stream audio/mpeg -> audio/x-float-array

Please help.

Comment: You might want to specify which library/service (and what service) you are using.

Comment: Hi, I am using ibm watson library. Service i am implementing is Speech-To-Text "com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:speech-to-text:6.11.0"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass your video through something like ffmpeg to extract the audio track, and pass the audio track to the Speech to Text Service.

Comment: Ok , this is working for me. Can you please help i am facing lagging issue between video playing and transcript text received from API. How can i overcome this issue? Tried websocket but not very clear about this concept.

Comment: There are a number of ways you could do this. You need to take into account latency - the time it takes for your audio to send to the service, be processed, and the transcription returned. You probably need to use the STT service in streaming mode. How long is your video? If it's long, you could use ffmpeg to split up the track by silences, and pass each one in turn to the STT service.